# Facebook setInitialize is deprecated but removing it causes inflating error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

As suggested here:

> The Facebook SDK is now auto initialized on Application start. If you
>   are using the Facebook SDK in the main process and don't need a
>   callback on SDK initialization completion you can now remove calls to
>   FacebookSDK.sdkInitialize. If you do need a callback, you should
>   manually invoke the callback in your code.

`Facebook.setInitalizer(context)` is now deprecated. The problem is that when I remove the line: `Facebook.setInitalizer(context)` as suggested I get an Inflating error on: `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton`:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/signin_activity_login_button_fb"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
/>
```

Error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
```

When I return the initalizer the error is gone. What should I do.

Also Gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

Comment: Have you given a permission to INTERNET in the manifest.xml?

Comment: yes i did add a permission

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too when I am using Firebase Authentication. But, I fixed that issue right now.

Step 1: Click "SDK Manager" button and download the latest version of Google Play service.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZthu.png)

Step 2: Then, click "build.gradle (Module: App)" and update these dependency of Google to align the version number is "12.0.1" and click "Sync".

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
```

Step 3: Check these code is already in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Step 4: Create a "ids.xml" file on this directory. File Path: app/res/values/ids.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!--
    Your Facebook App ID. See README.
-->
<!--  TODO(developer): REPLACE -->
<string name="facebook_app_id">REPLACE_ME</string>

<!--
  Your Twitter Key and Secret, see README.
-->
<!-- TODO(developer): REPLACE -->
<string name="twitter_consumer_key">REPLACE_ME</string>
<string name="twitter_consumer_secret">REPLACE_ME</string>
</resources>
```

Step4: Don't care about deprecated message. Just keep it in your activity is okay.

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```